# How can I solve this .htaccess rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to make this simple rewrite, but I'm probably wrong because it doesn't work.

**Original url format:** http://www.mydomain.nop/folder/component/option,com_seminar/cid,134/task,3/

**New url format:** http://www.mydomain.nop/folder/component/eventbooking/seminar/134

The variables I need are these:

.../component/option,com_seminar/cid,***num1***/task,**n*um2***/

(the one after 'task,' is a variable number like the other but not necessary for the new url)

This is my code which however reports a 404 error

```
RewriteEngine On
...
RewriteRule ^/component/option,com_seminar/cid,([^/]*)/task,([^/]*)/$ /component/eventbooking/seminar/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance and apologize for my not perfect english

PS. I would like the code to work even without the last / of the original url

Comment: When you configure rewriting in .htaccess, the path RewriteRule matches against never starts with a leading slash, that has been stripped off at that point already - so `^/…` will never match anything. And your URL starts with `folder/component/`, yet you try to match things starting with `component` – is the .htaccess in that folder? Then you might still need to modify the rewrite target, because `/component/…` might point one level to far up.

Comment: Use `^/?` at the beginning of your matching pattern, then the rules with work identical in dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") and in the real http server's host configuration. If in doubt do _not_ use dynamic configuration file for a ton of reasons.

Comment: @04FS Ok removed the `/` initial. The .htaccess is in the folder `folder` which is the folder where I have the joomla installation.
According to your indications I have tried various modifications but even so none does not work

Comment: Make sure you are not getting fooled by faulty redirects your browser might have already cached here. Clear the history, or test in a new private tab/window. And use `R=302` while you are still testing, to only get temporary redirects.